# Exclude 'SharePoint' URL from Search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, url, query

We have several documents with 'SharePoint' in the title but our Online URL also has sharepoint (https://***.sharepoint.com/).

When users search for sharepoint, it returns all results because all results have that in their URL. How can we exclude this portion of the URL from the search results?

Comment: I believe you can create a custom search result type (as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/dn135239.aspx)). Alternatively, when searching, you can scope the results by e.g. file type by adding `filetype:docx` to the search.

Answer (score 1):

You can try create Crawl Rule .

> **You can add a crawl rule to include or exclude specific paths when you crawl content**. When you include a path, you can provide alternative account credentials to crawl it. In addition to creating or editing crawl rules, you can test, delete, or reorder existing crawl rules.

Also note that

> The order of crawl rules is important, because the first rule that matches a particular set of content is the one that is applied.

Steps Involved:

- Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an
  administrator for the Search service application.
- In Central Administration, in the Application Management section,
  click Manage Service Applications.
- On the Manage Service Applications page, in the list of service
  applications, click the Search service application.
- On the Search Administration page, in the Crawling section, click
  Crawl Rules. The Manage Crawl Rules page appears.
- To create a new crawl rule, click **New Crawl Rule**.To edit an existing crawl rule, in the list of crawl rules, point to
  the name of the crawl rule that you want to edit, click the arrow
  that appears, and then click Edit.
- In the Crawl Configuration section, select **Include all items in this path**. Select this option if you want all items in the path to be crawled. If you select this option, you can further refine the inclusion by selecting any combination of the following:
- **Follow links on the URL without crawling the URL itself.** Select this option if you want to crawl links contained within the URL, but not the starting URL itself.
- In the Specify Authentication section, perform one of the
  appropriate actions (To allow anonymous access, select Anonymous access._
- Click OK

More details here: [Technet Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj219686.aspx)